# No such file or directory when running binary, though the binary exists

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, docker

I'm installing `minikube` as part of below `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/jnlp-agent-alpine
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 && \
        install minikube-linux-amd64 /home/jenkins/minikube -o jenkins -g jenkins -m 777 && \         
        rm minikube-linux-amd64
```

Once image is built and run:

```
$docker build -t app:latest .
$docker run -it app:latest bash

#minikube` binary exists

bash-5.1$ls -l minikube 
-rwxrwxrwx    1 jenkins  jenkins   74953166 Jul 19 15:44 minikube

#however running the binary `minikube` returns `No such file or directory` error:

bash-5.1$ ./minikube 
bash: ./minikube: No such file or directory
```

As part of debugging, I made `jenkins` user owner of `minikube` and set its permissions to be `777`, though it still didn't help.

Why does `No such file or directory` error pop and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `minikube` binary is linked against the GNU C library, but your image is based on Alpine which uses [musl](https://musl.libc.org/). Running `minikube` fails because the dynamic linker it specifies (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) isn’t present.

If you want to use `minikube`, you need to either find a musl-based build (or a static build), or switch to a base image which uses the GNU C library.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to run minikube using below command inside the container:

`/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 minikube`

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548061/1264304) answer

The explanation is in @Stephen Kitt answer

Comment: Wow, I wouldn’t have thought that would work!